# Best way to find ElasticBeanstalk Name from an EC2 running inside EB AutoScale group

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to programmatically in PHP figure out which ElasticBeanstalk environment an EC2 is currently residing in, from inside the EC2 itself.

Am I going to have to go around the houses:

- Describe ElasticBeanstalk Applications

  For each of those, describe environments

  For each of those, describe resources

  For each of those, look for my own instance ID?

Any help with an efficient way of doing this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the environment name as an environment variable?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.managing.html